# An additive secret sharing-based protocol against malicious adversaries

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation

There is a two-party computation protocol based on 2-out-of-2 additive secret sharing in Figure 1. Party $P_0$ holds secret shares $[a]_0, [b]_0$, and party $P_1$ holds secret shares $[a]_1, [b]_1$ where $[a]_0 + [a]_1 = a$ and $[b]_0 + [b]_1 = b$. We assume that $P_0$ and $P_1$ have obtained Beaver's triples $([u]_i, [v]_i, [z]_i)$ and want to securely compute $c = a \cdot b$ and obtain the secret shares $c_0$ and $c_1$ such that $c_0 + c_1 = c$ respectively. It works as follows:

1. $P_0$ computes $[e]_0 = [a]_0 - [u]_0, [f]_0 = [b]_0 - [v]_0$ and sends $[e]_0, [f]_0$ to $P_1$, and $P_1$ computes $[e]_1 = [a]_1 - [u]_1, [f]_1 = [b]_1 - [v]_1$ and sends $[e]_1, [f]_1$ to $P_0$.
2. $P_0$ and $P_1$ obtain $e = [e]_0 + [e]_1, f = [f]_0 + [f]_1$.
3. $P_i$ compute $[c]_i = i \cdot ef + f \cdot [u]_i + e \cdot [v]_i + [z]_i$

[image: 2PC]
Figure 1 the two-party computation protocol based on 2-out-of-2 additive secret sharing

Here, we consider the two properties of correctness and privacy (we directly follow the definition of security from [Lindell's paper: How To Simulate It](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046). It is clear that this protocol is correct and secure against semi-honest (a.k.a, honest-but-curious) adversaries. For malicious security, this protocol obviously fails to satisfy correctness since the adversary can perform wrong computations. However, I wonder whether this protocol is secure against malicious adversaries?

In my sense, this protocol is secure against malicious adversaries since honest party's inputs (i.e., [a] and [b]) isn't leaked. But here are some possible attacks that confuse me (assume $P_0$ is the corrupted party):

1. $P_0$ does not use the correct Beaver's triples $([u]_0, [v]_0, [z]_0)$, but uses specific $([u']_0, [v']_0, [z']_0)$ to carry out attacks, trying to obtain the input of honest party $P_1$.
2. $P_0$ executes the protocol correctly, but randomly selects a number as the final result $[c]_0$.
3. If $P_0$ and $P_1$ need to execute the protocol depicted in Figure 1 multiple times, is it possible for $P_0$ to gather interaction information in a way that reveals $P_1$'s input, especially if $P_0$ deviates from generating uniformly distributed random numbers (when random numbers are required)?

I interpret that the described attack behaviors could impact the correctness of the protocol without compromising its privacy. The protocol remains secure against malicious adversaries. Moreover, if my goal is to ensure both the correctness and security of the protocol, how should I approach its design?

Comment: I believe there's a typo in $[c]_i = i \cdot ef + f \cdot [u]_i + e \cdot [v]_i + [z]_i$. With this expression, $P_0$ does not compute the correct multiplicative share. Also, can you expand a bit on your attack? The way the question is asked presupposes a trusted dealer, or at least no triple generation protocol is specified. If we assume a secure triple generation, then $P_0$ receives no information on $P_1$'s share. But this, the situation is different should we replace the dealer with some protocol.